# Rails / language with TinyTDS and SQL Server Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am actually using TinyTDS and activerecord-sql-adapter gems, to connect to my DB.
Every error messages are displayed in English (i.e : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'rofl'.:)

Is there a way to have this kind of messages displayed in another language ? I was not able to find any parameterizable file or something else about this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "SET LANGUAGE ..." to the one of your choice after connecting. The SQL Server adapter provides a callback method to configure each connection for things just like this. See this section of the README.

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#configure-connection--app-name

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I have my error messages in French :)
I wrote an initializer to achieve that (see below).

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.class_eval do
   def configure_connection
  raw_connection_do "SET LANGUAGE French"
   end
end`